# How to disable eslint eqeqeq?

Tags: eslint

I use create-react-app and just want to add rules to my **package.json**. I see that I can disable this rule, but how? In the official document, only the phrase "If you don't want to enforce a style for using equality operators, then it's safe to disable this rule."

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/docs/rules/eqeqeq.md#when-not-to-use-it

I found that i can write this:

> ```
> // package.json
> {
>   "name": "mypackage",
>   ...,
>   "eslintConfig": {
>     "rules": {
>       "eqeqeq": "off"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

## but it not works.

I would like to clarify the question. The reason for my question here is not that I don't know how to disable the rule, I do not know how to disable it in the package.json. I just don't want to clutter up the project's root directory with an additional file.

Comment: `"eslintConfig": {
 "extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
 ],
 "rules": {
  "eqeqeq": "off"
 }
},` works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 4):

Go to your project root folder (where is packaje.json) and create a file named .eslintrc.json

Inside this add the following:

```json
    {
      "rules": {
        "eqeqeq": "off"
      }
    }
```

Then re launch the app and the rule should be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "off"
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Look at the last rule**

Now as how to turn it to "smart" rather than "off" I'm yet to figure that out.

** Notice how its in the "files": [*.html] or "files": [*.ts]. I put mine in the .html rules because my errors were in html files but if they were in a ts file I'd put the rule there instead.

EDIT 1: I found this website useful https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/blob/master/.eslintrc.json

Comment: NOTE: The answer you choose depends on what you are linting and where it gets invoked e.g. html files VIA ng lint (linting templates through angular) 

@Zaf - Thank you for the angular variation...

Answer (score 1):

you can add an eslint configuration file .eslintrc and disable the rules you want inside it.

[docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats)

Answer (score 0):

You may locate the `eslint` configuration file, and change `eqeqeq` rule to `off`:

`eqeqeq: 'off',`

Also, make sure that you don't override the setting farther.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a suitable solution to the question. I met information that you can not create a separate configuration file

Comment: I think @Hoxz is right. you cannot create a separate config file for this

Answer (score 0):

Go to .eslintrc.js then add

```
rules: {
  eqeqeq: 'off',
},
```